# golang generate rest api documentation using gorilla/mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a restful service in golang running in production, and using gorrila mux. Is there an extension utility available, which I can add to generate nice restful api documention?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, but you can use this excellent tool https://github.com/adams-sarah/test2doc to generate documentation